# Cohomology of Siegel modular varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

$\mathcal{A}_g(N)$ is the moduli space of principally polarized abelian varieties with a level $N$ structure.

Set $C_g=\displaystyle{\lim_{\rightarrow}} H^3(\mathcal{A}_g(N), \mathbb{F}_p)$ where the limit is taken over $N$.

Is $C_g$ a finite $\mathbb{F}_p$-module for sufficiently large $g$?

Comment: What kind of cohomology are you taking here? Topological (Betti) cohomology of $\mathcal{A}_g(N)(\mathbb{C})$, or something fancier?

Comment: singular cohomology of complex points